# How does the Comparator works with Arrays.sort?

Tags: java, arrays, comparator

My question is how comparator interface works with arrays.sort method ?
for ex :

```
  Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<String>(){
        public int compare(String first, String second){
            System.out.println("Comparator : (second+first)  "+(second+first)+" first+ second "+(first+second)+" comparing : "+(second+first).compareTo(first+second));
            return (second+first).compareTo(first+second);
        }
    });
```

Intput

```
arr = {"34","4","23","15"}
```

So basically the above snippet is to arrange the array to form the largest number.

output will be as `{"4","34","23","15"}`

I printed the intermediate results and output is as intended but i cant grasp how it works.Can someone say how it is sorted by using returned integers from compare method?

```
Comparator : (second+first)  344 first+ second 434 comparing : -1
Comparator : (second+first)  423 first+ second 234 comparing : 2 
Comparator : (second+first)  3423 first+ second 2334 comparing : 1 
Comparator : (second+first)  3415 first+ second 1534 comparing : 2
Comparator : (second+first)  2315 first+ second 1523 comparing : 1
```

Comment: The two strings are compared in reading direction. On the first mismatching character, the difference between their code point value is returned. If the strings were equal, 0 would be returned. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list

Comment: What is really the question ?

Comment: my question was comapare method returns postive or negative or zero value ,with that how array is being sorted ?

Comment: @KarthikRaja maybe read the answer below, i've explained the 5 rules ;)

Comment: @azro thanks man, it helped now i can logically understand how it works.

Comment: So don't hesitate to accept the answer if it's ok ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rules for `a.compareTo(b)`

- `returns negative value` : `a is before b`
- `returns 0` : `a equal to b`
- `return positive value` : `a is after b`

---

Because the parameter are `first, second` and you compare like `second.compareTo(first)` you'll get reverse order :

```
(second+first)   344 first+ second  434 comparing : -1 >>   4 is before 34
(second+first)   423 first+ second  234 comparing : 2  >>  23 is after   4
(second+first)  3423 first+ second 2334 comparing : 1  >>  23 is after  34
(second+first)  3415 first+ second 1534 comparing : 2  >>  15 is after  34
(second+first)  2315 first+ second 1523 comparing : 1  >>  15 is after  23
```

> With these 5 `before/after` rules the order is `4 34 23 15`
>
> Which is *`Reverse Lexical Order`* (Lexical because use of `String`, reverse because compare second to first)

---

*Details for one case*

- The `sort` method will compare `4` and `34`, so `first=4` and `second=34`
- you compute `"344".compareTo("434")`, because 344 is before 434 is lexical order you got -1
- Because of `-1` the `sort` method will remember that `4` is before `34`